# Hide components beind transparent header

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sass, header, transparent

I'm a noob. I've been trying to find a solution that works for my problem for several days, but I've been unable to find it. The other posts on Stackoverflow didn't help me. I have a transparent header on the web that I am making, when the scroll is done the elements go under it and are hidden behind the letters of the header, but they are not hidden behind the reserved space of the header. Has anyone done something like that?

I am using Next.js 13.4.5

If you need to see my code, tell me and I will post it on GitHub
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIcCi.png

Comment: *I know that a position fixed element has no reserved space!!!

Comment: It's not clear to me what your desired outcome is. Do you want the content behind the header to be visible or do you not want it to be visible?

Comment: I Don't want the content behind the header to be visible

Comment: If your page background is simply a uniform solid color you could set the header's background to the same color and it would hide anything behind it which has a lower z-index. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: no, the background is an image. it could be seen on that image I posted:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIcCi.png I put that black div behind for you to see that the letters are above the black div